# Using a domain object as a MongoDB document ID with Spring Data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

## Background

One idea I recently picked up from learning about Domain Driven Design (DDD) is that it can be nice to wrap data types, such as Strings and primitives, with domain objects that have meaningful names. For example, if I have a `com.example.Account` domain object that I am going to store in MongoDB, it might have an id field that is of type `java.lang.String`. Instead, it might be nice to have the id field be of type `com.example.AccountId` since this reads fairly well and helps as a kind of self documentation of the code. It also could be a compile time defence against someone accidentally passing another kind of id that also happens to be a String...

I have run into some trouble trying to achieve this using Spring Data MongoDB

## Example

### Using A String

I started with an Account object that just has a single field called "id" of type `java.lang.String`. My Spring Data Repository definition was as follows:

```
public interface AccountRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Account, String> {}
```

This works fine and I can save instances of accounts which will be given automatically generated MongoDB identifiers, such as: `5436fd21300415af8c9201e0`.

### Using A Custom Type

First I define an object as follows:

```
public class AccountId implements Serializable {

private final String id;

public AccountId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

}
```

Then I change the type of the id field in account to be `AccountId` and finally change the repository definition to be:

```
public interface AccountRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Account, AccountId> {}
```

When I try to save an instance of Account I get an exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Cannot autogenerate id of type com.example.AccountId for entity of type com.example.Account!
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.assertUpdateableIdIfNotSet(MongoTemplate.java:1149)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doSave(MongoTemplate.java:878)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.save(MongoTemplate.java:833)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.save(SimpleMongoRepository.java:72)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

What (if anything) can I do to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: Try adding setter and default constructor.

Comment: I know that this is a little old now - I never did adequately solve this. I tried a default constructor and setter with no luck. It seems that the method org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate#assertUpdateableIdIfNotSet makes a check to see if the type of the Id field is of type ObjectId, String or BigInteger. Since my AccountId is none of these the exception is thrown. I've ended up manually setting the AccountId object prior to persisting by calling new ObjectId().toHexString() and passing the result to construct an AccountId. Not ideal, but it seems to work.

Comment: @DavidGoate - Did you ever find a better solution to this? I am facing exactly the same problem. I can solve it the way you have described, but I'd much rather have Spring know how to autogenerate an instance of my ID class.

Comment: @Nathan - I didn't ever find a better way unfortunately but I haven't tried searching again or using the original approach since this post so perhaps newer versions of Spring Data play more nicely? Or are you having this exact problem on the latest version?

Comment: Spring Mongo 1.9.4, and no, it doesnt play any nicer :( The problem area is the class MongoSimpleTypes, with its static AUTOGENERATED_ID_TYPES. This only contains ObjectId, String and BigInteger, and there is no way to inject other types or behaviours . All in all, not very 'spring' to be honest :( Never mind